# Dictionary value as function with parameter

Tags: python

I'd like to do something like this (this is a trivial example, but it shows the problem):

```py
a = {'a' : 3, 'b': (lambda x: x * 3)(a['a'])}
```

but I want the value of `a['b']` to get automatically updated when `a['a']` changes.

In this case of course `a['b']` gets evaluated only at the beginning, so I get this:

```py
>>> a = {'a': 3, 'b': (lambda x: x * 3)(a['a'])}
>>> a
{'a': 3, 'b': 9}
>>> a['a'] = 4
>>> a
{'a': 4, 'b': 9}
```

What I want is this instead:

```
>>> a = {'a': 3, 'b':(lambda x: x * 3)(a['a'])}
>>> a
{'a': 3, 'b': 9}
>>> a['a'] = 4
>>> a
{'a': 4, 'b': 16}      <<<<<<<<<< change
```

Does anyone know if there's an easy/pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: The code wouldn't run. Because ```a``` is not finished being declared and you are referencing ```a```

Comment: To do this you'd have to inherit or compose a dictionary and implement this behaviour in `__getitem__`.

Comment: You basically want a `@property` as a dict item, which, TL;DR, isn't really possible. The closest and easiest would be to write a dict-like class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that if you call the function upon retrieval:

```
a = {'a': 3, 'b': (lambda: a['a']*3)}

a["b"]()
# 9

a["a"] = 5
a["b"]()
# 15
```

But there are certainly better ways to such property like behavior.

Comment: this is not bad, interesting that if I add () inside the definition of a it fails to update.
Thanks!

Comment: The point is tht there is nothing dynamic left if you call it already upon definition (besides the fact that this doesn't work here).